# How to go back from native Android settings screen?

Tags: android, android-activity

In my app, the user goes from `ActivityA` to `ActivityB`. `ActivityB` displays an **NFC Settings** button. When the user clicks that button, this code is executed to show the native NFC Settings screen:

```
Intent intent;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
  intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_NFC_SETTINGS);
} else {
  intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS);
}
startActivity(intent);
showToast("Press Back button when done");
```

The problem I'm having is that when the user is viewing the native NFC Settings screen and presses the device's back button, they are taken all the way back to `ActivityA`.

Is there a clean way to solve this problem so that the user goes back to `ActivityB`, as required/expected?

Comment: Use `startActivityForResult(...)`.

Comment: Are you sure that you are not calling `finish()` sometime after `startActivity()`?

Comment: Do you need to [intercept the back button](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+intercept+back+tutton&oq=android+intercept+back+tutton&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.6506j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)?

Comment: @Onik Your suggestion has done the trick. Would you like to add it as an answer so I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the application process was killed in background, although in this case `Android` would have restored the back stack... Make sure you are not calling `finish()` after `startActivity()` in `ActivityB`. Or try using `startActivityForResult()` instead of `startActivity()`, that is not a panacea though!